# How to I combine my random number with a random word from a list?

Tags: python

I've been stuck trying to combine my a random word from a list and a random number between 10 and 100. I can get the individual lines to run, but when I run the together I get this error:

```
    if not len(seq):
           ^^^^^^^^
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len().
```

[Here is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYktp.png)

I was expecting the color to be printed with a random number next to it.

Comment: Please update your question with the *text* of your code.

Comment: When doing number = str you are assigning number to be the type string

Comment: Just remove lines 139 and 140…